# Не передать значение в состояние, React

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Не понимаю, почему я не могу передать значение в состояние. На первый взгляд все правильно. loginStatus2, равняться значению по умолчанию, хотя он должен быть равен true/false в зависимости от того что храниться в loggedInUser.

```
import { React,useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";



const Dashboard = () => {
    let [loginStatus2, setLoginStatus2] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
      const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("loginStatus");
        if (loggedInUser) {
        setLoginStatus2(loggedInUser);
        console.log(loginStatus2)
        console.log(loggedInUser)
            }
      },[])
    if (!loginStatus2){
      return <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
    }else{
      return(
      <>
       <Header/>
        <Footer />
        <div>
            <p>Welcome to your Dashboard</p>
        </div>
      </>
      )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Что у вас происходит? Вас перекидывает на login?

Comment: А что хранится в `loggedInUser`?

Comment: @SwaD да на логин перекидывает, так как loginStatus2 хранит в себе null

Comment: @OliverPatterson он хранит в себе true/false, которое храниться в  localstorage.

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что в localStorage хранятся строки и ваша проверка не даст нужного результата? И почему хранит `null`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, даже если строки, ее можно преобразовать потом, я просто не очень понимаю, почему я не могу передать состоянию то что храниться в  loggedInUser.

Comment: А вы уверены, что правильный ключ написали в `getItem`? И Зачем тут нужен лишний `useEffect` (useLayoutEffect кстати будет выгоднее), если можно этот кейс обработать при создании `useState`? `useState(() => { // ... })`

Comment: @OliverPatterson Дело не в ключах, а в жизненном цикле компонента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том, что компонент сначала монтируется, а уже после этого вызывается **useEffect**. На момент первого рендера, состояние **false(null)**, что вызывало переадресацию пользователя, как следовательно, мы получили нежелательное поведение.

Избавить от этого можно, добавив флаг(Например **isReady**) проверки пользователя:

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  const [loginStatus2, setLoginStatus2] = useState(null);
  const [isReady, setReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("loginStatus");
    if (loggedInUser) {
      setLoginStatus2(loggedInUser);
      console.log(loginStatus2);
      console.log(loggedInUser);
    }
    setReady(true); // Проверка выполнена
    }, []);

  if (isReady)
    if (!loginStatus2){
      return <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
    } else {
      return(
      <>
      <Header/>
        <Footer />
        <div>
            <p>Welcome to your Dashboard</p>
        </div>
      </>
      )
    }
    else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
}
```

Таким образом, до тех пор, пока не выполнится проверка пользователя(не сработает **useEffect**), компонент будет отображать *Loading*, после проверки, уже про состоянию **loginStatus2** выберет, что отображать.

Comment: Тестировал в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dubinsky-196xfj?file=/src/App.js). Там оставил console.log() что бы было видно, в какой последовательности что отрабатывает

Comment: Не проще ли использовать в таком случае `useLayoutEffect`?